# AJAX Page Loading on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to install the "[Advanced AJAX Page Loader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/)" plugin on my Wordpress site.  The theme installation says to "make sure your theme has the content area wrapped in a tag such as a DIV with an id attribute called "content"".

My theme has what looks like a variable div wrapper around my content in the page.php file:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="type-page" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

        <!-- page-title -->
        <?php if($themify->page_title != "yes"): ?>
            <h1 class="page-title" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /page-title -->

        <div class="page-content entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">

            <?php the_content(); ?>
```

My questions are, does it look like I am looking at the right section of code, i.e.

If so, how would I identify the corresponding div wrapper, which looks like it's variable based on page ID:  ?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are asking you to wrap your content area in a div with an id of 'content'. Your code above doesn't have that;

```
<div id="content">
    // content here
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the plugin settings allows me to input a "Content Element ID", which is the div id of the content for my theme.  It seems my theme has a div wrapper of "div id="page-<?php the_ID(); ", which won't work because it's variable.

Comment: The script you are using will be looking for an element with id 'content', which I imagine is where it will insert the data. Just try putting '<php the_content(); ?>' part you have above inside the tags from my answer and see if it works